# Removing bounty removes all bounties from same user?

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, moderation

On this question:

[AutoMapper vs ValueInjecter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663577/automapper-vs-valueinjecter#question)

I removed the current bounty and locked the question, due to the user misusing the bounty system for promotional purposes.

When I did this, *all rewarded bounties on all answers disappeared.*  Is this by design?  Shouldn't it just remove the active bounty?

Also, when I subsequently attempted to do a rep recalc on the user who posted the bounties, I got the "Oops, Something Bad Happened" error:

https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/admin/users/112100/recalc-rep

Comment: Er...Is it a coincidence that *the user's Gravatar is the "Workin on ur problemz" cat?* :P

Comment: LOL @ the cat. I haven't seen it before

Comment: Perhaps it's old code that just removes all bounties for the question by the user, not taking into account that users can now offer multiple bounties on the same question (in series)?

Comment: How does someone misusing the bounty system for promotional purposes?  Isn't that the point of a bounty, to promote your question?

Comment: @user147272: Not when you're the owner of the product for which the bounties are providing visibility, and you've indiscriminately posted and awarded four bounties in a row (it wasn't the question asker who posted the bounties).

Answer (score 6):

Whew - it was a bug in the display code that incorrectly relied on a question's `BountyAmount` property... which is cleared by the moderator function "Remove Bounty."

This has been fixed and will be pushed this evening.

However, the rep recalc you did exposed another bug, but that one's not my fault :)

<sub>But I'll fix it, anyway.</sub>